# how o display a variable in text field

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

i am a newbi in flash as3.. the problen i am facing in my project is i want to display a counter in my HUD using TextField();but cannot as it inly allows strings... i tried the followinf lines of code

```
     private var _counter:Number=4;
    counter.text=String (_counter);
```

and in the TextField function

```
    var bmpFontTF:TextField = new TextField(1000, 1000, counter, "font", 200);
```

its not working... how to display variables using textfield()..?

Answer (score 0):

`counter` isn't your TextField, `bmpFontTf` is.

```
bmpFontTF.text = _count.toString();
```

It looks like you have this completely messed up, though. You are setting up your TextField as if it were a TextFormat (TextField has no constructor arguments).

So...

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
var bmpFontTF:TextFormat = new TextFormat( /* your args here */ );
tf.defaultTextFormat = bmpFontTF;

tf.text = _counter.toString();
```

Comment: but textField always require atleast 3 argumnts

Comment: Not sure where you are getting that from. `TextField` has **zero** arguments. See the [LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#TextField())

Answer (score 0):

to set up the data to be displayed on the TextFormat you have tu use the 'text' attribute:

```
var myTextField : TextField = new TextField();
myTextField.text = "some text";
```

just keep in mind that .text only accepts a String as value, so if you want to show any other value like a Number, you have to convert it to string with its own .toString() method

```
myTextField.text = someNumber.toString();
```

keep in mind that not all objects have the .toString() method.

also you can append more data after your number using + operator

```
myTextField.text = "the number is: " + someNumber.toString();
```